# MongoDB query filter price

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm faily new to MongoDB, and trying to filter a price within a range. Instead of just filtering on a specific element, I first need to check if a special price exists. If a special price do exist, and it's within the from/to date, it should be used instead of the normal price.

What you see below is my attempt at this, but unfortunately its not working. How can I do this correctly?

Best regards

```
db.products.find({
   "shops":1,
   "categories":59,
   "options":{
      "$elemMatch":{
         "quantity":{
            "$gt":0
         }
      }
   },
   "$or":[
      {
         "$and":[
            {
               "$and":[
                  {
                     "options.pricing.special.from":{
                        "$exists":true
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "options.pricing.special.to":{
                        "$exists":true
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "$or":[
                  {
                     "$and":[
                        {
                           "options.pricing.special.from":{
                              "$gt":{
                                 "sec":1331291423,
                                 "usec":76000
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "options.pricing.special.to":{
                              "$lt":{
                                 "sec":1331291423,
                                 "usec":76000
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "options.pricing.price":{
                              "$gte":0,
                              "$lte":0
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "$and":[
                        {
                           "options.pricing.special.from":{
                              "$lte":{
                                 "sec":1331291423,
                                 "usec":76000
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "options.pricing.special.to":{
                              "$gte":{
                                 "sec":1331291423,
                                 "usec":76000
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "options.pricing.special.price":{
                              "$gte":0,
                              "$lte":0
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "$and":[
            {
               "$and":[
                  {
                     "options.pricing.special.from":{
                        "$exists":false
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "options.pricing.special.to":{
                        "$exists":false
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "options.pricing.price":{
                  "$gte":0,
                  "$lte":0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}).sort({
   "created_at":-1
})
```

**Sample document:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f59047d8b446bac05000000"),
  "created_at" : new Date("Wed, 11 Feb 2009 13:54:09 GMT +01:00"),
  "modified_at" : new Date("Thu, 08 Mar 2012 20:11:17 GMT +01:00"),
  "sku" : "K2 - N30052005",
  "name" : {
    "en" : "Pants - Nintendo",
    "da" : "Bukser - Nintendo"
  },
  "description" : {
    "en" : "<p>Super fed buks fra Designers Remix Collection. De har store lommer\r\nved hofterne, som giver buksen et lækkert ridebuks-look. De har smalle\r\nben, som gør modellen super feminin, samtidig med de er højtaljede.\r\nBrug dem med en top eller skjorte, samt et par lækre stiletter.  </p>\r\n<ul>\r\n    <li>65 % polyester</li>\r\n    <li>35 % viscose </li>\r\n    <li>Buksen skal sendes til rens - Stryges på indersiden, for at holde den skinnende overflade</li>\r\n</ul>",
    "da" : "<p>Super fed buks fra Designers Remix Collection. De har store lommer\r\nved hofterne, som giver buksen et lækkert ridebuks-look. De har smalle\r\nben, som gør modellen super feminin, samtidig med de er højtaljede.\r\nBrug dem med en top eller skjorte, samt et par lækre stiletter.&nbsp; </p>\r\n<ul>\r\n    <li>65 % polyester</li>\r\n    <li>35 % viscose </li>\r\n    <li>Buksen skal sendes til rens - Stryges på indersiden, for at holde den skinnende overflade</li>\r\n</ul>"
  },
  "url_key" : {
    "en" : "designers-remix-collection-pants-nintendo",
    "da" : "designers-remix-collection-bukser-nintendo"
  },
  "categories" : [15, 68, 84],
  "shops" : [2],
  "images" : [{
      "src" : "designers-remix-collection-bukser-nintendo-1-1.jpg",
      "alt" : ""
    }, {
      "src" : "designers-remix-collection-bukser-nintendo-1-2.jpg",
      "alt" : ""
    }, {
      "src" : "designers-remix-collection-bukser-nintendo-1-3.jpg",
      "alt" : ""
    }, {
      "src" : "designers-remix-collection-bukser-nintendo-1-4.jpg",
      "alt" : ""
    }],
  "options" : [{
      "size" : {
        "da" : "34",
        "en" : "34"
      },
      "quantity" : 0,
      "shipping" : {
        "weight" : 0,
        "depth" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "width" : 0
      },
      "pricing" : {
        "price" : 129900,
        "cost" : 48100,
        "retail" : 0,
        "vat" : 25,
        "special" : {
          "price" : 38900,
          "from" : new Date("Fri, 01 Jul 2011 00:00:00 GMT +02:00"),
          "to" : new Date("Sun, 30 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT +02:00")
        },
        "savings" : 91000,
        "pct_savings" : 70.0
      },
      "sortable_sizes" : {
        "da" : ["XS"],
        "en" : ["XS"]
      }
    }, {
      "size" : {
        "da" : "36",
        "en" : "36"
      },
      "quantity" : 0,
      "shipping" : {
        "weight" : 0,
        "depth" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "width" : 0
      },
      "pricing" : {
        "price" : 129900,
        "cost" : 48100,
        "retail" : 0,
        "vat" : 25,
        "special" : {
          "price" : 38900,
          "from" : new Date("Fri, 01 Jul 2011 00:00:00 GMT +02:00"),
          "to" : new Date("Sun, 30 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT +02:00")
        },
        "savings" : 91000,
        "pct_savings" : 70.0
      },
      "sortable_sizes" : {
        "da" : ["S"],
        "en" : ["S"]
      }
    }, {
      "size" : {
        "da" : "38",
        "en" : "38"
      },
      "quantity" : 0,
      "shipping" : {
        "weight" : 0,
        "depth" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "width" : 0
      },
      "pricing" : {
        "price" : 129900,
        "cost" : 48100,
        "retail" : 0,
        "vat" : 25,
        "special" : {
          "price" : 38900,
          "from" : new Date("Fri, 01 Jul 2011 00:00:00 GMT +02:00"),
          "to" : new Date("Sun, 30 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT +02:00")
        },
        "savings" : 91000,
        "pct_savings" : 70.0
      },
      "sortable_sizes" : {
        "da" : ["M"],
        "en" : ["M"]
      }
    }, {
      "size" : {
        "da" : "40",
        "en" : "40"
      },
      "quantity" : 0,
      "shipping" : {
        "weight" : 0,
        "depth" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "width" : 0
      },
      "pricing" : {
        "price" : 129900,
        "cost" : 48100,
        "retail" : 0,
        "vat" : 25,
        "special" : {
          "price" : 38900,
          "from" : new Date("Fri, 01 Jul 2011 00:00:00 GMT +02:00"),
          "to" : new Date("Sun, 30 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT +02:00")
        },
        "savings" : 91000,
        "pct_savings" : 70.0
      },
      "sortable_sizes" : {
        "da" : ["L"],
        "en" : ["L"]
      }
    }],
  "attributes" : {
    "size" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Størrelse",
        "en" : "Size"
      },
      "type" : "select",
      "required" : true,
      "visible" : true,
      "option" : true,
      "sortable" : false
    },
    "color" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Farve",
        "en" : "Color"
      },
      "type" : "select",
      "required" : true,
      "visible" : true,
      "option" : false,
      "sortable" : false,
      "default" : {
        "da" : "Sort",
        "en" : "Black"
      },
      "value" : {
        "da" : ["Sort"],
        "en" : ["Black"]
      }
    },
    "type" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Type",
        "en" : "Type"
      },
      "required" : false,
      "option" : false,
      "sortable" : false,
      "value" : {
        "da" : "tempType",
        "en" : "tempType"
      }
    },
    "manufacturer" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Designer",
        "en" : "Designer"
      },
      "required" : false,
      "option" : false,
      "sortable" : false,
      "value" : {
        "da" : "Designers Remix Collection",
        "en" : "Designers Remix Collection"
      }
    },
    "sortable_colors" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Sorterbare farver",
        "en" : "Sortable Colors"
      },
      "type" : "system",
      "required" : false,
      "option" : false,
      "visible" : false,
      "sortable" : true,
      "value" : {
        "en" : ["Black"],
        "da" : ["Sort"]
      }
    },
    "sortable_sizes" : {
      "name" : {
        "da" : "Sorterbare størrelser",
        "en" : "Sortable Sizes"
      },
      "type" : "system",
      "required" : false,
      "option" : true,
      "visible" : false,
      "sortable" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample documents.

Comment: Included in the question as requested :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the price range to 35000 to 40000, so it would match the special price. Then I have a second example with 35000 to 150000, to match the main price. Hope this helps, in any case.

I think the key part of the query you are missing is "elemMatch". Your schema probably could be made easier to query, also, by not using an array with embedded objects for the pricing attributes.

```
  // testing first part of the $or
  var query = {$or: 
     [{"options":
        {
        $elemMatch:
           {"pricing.special.price":{$exists:true}, 
            "pricing.special.from":{$lt:new Date()},
            "pricing.special.to":{$gt:new Date()},
            "pricing.special.price":{$gt:35000},
            "pricing.special.price":{$lt:40000}
           }
        }
     },
     {"options":
        {$elemMatch: 
           {
              "pricing.price":{$gt:35000},
              "pricing.price":{$lt:40000}
           }
        }
     }]
  };
```

And this also matches.

```
  // testing out of the date range... and increasing the max price
  var query = {$or: 
     [{"options":
        {
        $elemMatch:
           {"pricing.special.price":{$exists:true}, 
            "pricing.special.from":{$lt:new Date("Jan 1, 2014")},
            "pricing.special.to":{$gt:new Date("Jan 1, 2014")},
            "pricing.special.price":{$gt:35000},
            "pricing.special.price":{$lt:150000}
           }
        }
     },
     {"options":
        {$elemMatch: 
           {
              "pricing.price":{$gt:35000},
              "pricing.price":{$lt:150000}
           }
        }
     }]
  };
```